# CSV parsing in Java: how do I split this token?

Tags: java, parsing, csv

I've got string in my CSV file uploaded on server in the form of:

```
21-June-2012 Football MU-Chelsea London (first row)
22-June-2012 Basketball NY-MY New York (second row)
```

When I do CSV parsing with the code below:

```java
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(stream);
ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer (50);int current = 0;
int current = 0;
while ((current = bis.read()) != -1){
    baf.append((byte)current);
}
String stockTxt =  new String (baf.toByteArray());  
String [] tokens = stockTxt.split(",");
String date_CSV     = tokens [2];
String time_CSV     = tokens [3];
String game_CSV     = tokens [4];
String gamedesc_CSV = tokens [5];
String venue_CSV    = tokens [6];
```

It shows the result:

```
token [0] = 21-June-2012 
token [1] = Football 
token [2] = MU-Chelsea 
token [3] = London 22-June-2012 
token [4] = Basketball 
token [5] = NY-MY
token [6] = New York
```

For the token `[3]` my expected reslt is London and my expected result for token 4 is `22-June-2012`. How do I do the splitting for this?

Comment: CSV stands for 'Comma Separated Values' though your record samples do not seem to have any commas

Comment: Daniel, it is in CSV Excel File, so the comma is not visible..

Comment: By the way, you should read the file via a `Reader`, not an `InputStream`, since you are interested in the characters from the file, not the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Each row is on its own line, so you need to read your input line by line first and split that.

Comment: Even if you don't read the file line by line, you already know how to *split* the text into smaller chunks. So first split on linebreaks (`[\r\n]+`), and then on commas.

Comment: @user1282157 As you're not already doing true byte-to-character conversion, you could use a DataInputStream to read lines. The true character equivalent would be a BufferedReader.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that the data is in “Excel CSV format” you should search for a library that can handle this format. There are several which you can use for free. After that, reading the file gets very simple, since you don't need to be concerned about the file format anymore. Your code should only be concerned about `readLine` and `readField`, not about handling the IO stuff itself.